# Entity Framework Core .NET CLI

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, command-line-interface, asp.net-core-2.0

I don't know why but I have problem with CLI on my Mac. I did everything like on this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations?view=aspnetcore-2.0 (trying to make migrations work with SQLLite) but after writing "dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate" command I am getting:

[image]

If I write "dotnet --info" command in terminal this is what I get:

```
Zestaw .NET Core SDK (odzwierciedlenie dowolnego pliku global.json):
 Version:   2.2.100-preview1-008932
 Commit:    da34f7eaab

Środowisko uruchomieniowe:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.13
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.13-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.100-preview1-008932/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.0-rtm-26515-03
  Commit:  caa7b7e2ba

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  1.0.0-preview2-1-003177 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  1.0.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.1.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.1.200 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.2.100-preview1-008932 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0-rtm-30752 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0-rtm-30752 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.7 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0-rtm-26515-03 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
MacBook-Pro-Tomasz:~ tomaszzmudzinski$
```

Comment: Also what does `dotnet --version` report back?

Comment: Result of "dotnet --version" command is 2.2.100-preview1-008932

Comment: @FoundNil any ideas why it's not working?:)

Comment: It should be working.  However your installation might be corrupt.  What does `dotnet --info` spit out?

Comment: @FoundNil I edited the post and added info about what I am getting after "dotnet --info" command in terminal. Please take a look ;)

Comment: I'm not sure.  If my edit doesn't work I would uninstall dotnet and reinstall the new sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised its not working.  You could try passing in a different runtime.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.7</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: .NET Core SDK is already installed, so this is other case, but still thanks ;)